# Past Date Validation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I am currently having troubles creating a code where when the user clicks on a past date for a booking system it will give a alert(Error) message.

I have managed to get it working for the past date. So when the use clicks on a past date on the date-picker calender, it gives them an error of "Invalid Date". The trouble i am having is when the use clicks on today's date and submit it gives an error acting like its a past date which it isn't.

The code i have used for this is:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var selectedText = document.getElementById('date1').value;
   var selectedDate = new Date(selectedText);
   var now = new Date;
      alert(now);
      alert(selectedDate);
   if (selectedDate < now) {
    document.getElementById("PastDateError").textContent = "Invalid Date";
   }
      else {
        document.getElementById("PastDateError").textContent = ''; 
    }
 
  }
```

Another issue i am having is that as the  date on html is using the element tags of  and not type="date". It does not predict give an error if i type random numbers, special character or letter. I tried researching on this but could not find anything. I need a way where i can allow users to only enter the date using the format of dd-mm-yyyy. So meaning using the special character of "-" other than that should give an error along with going over obviously 31 days or 12 months.

Comment: I can't see what form the date has in your form, but if it's only the day, it will be at 00:00:00 implicitly, and "now" is usually past midnight. Try adding '23:59:59' to your day?

Comment: Where shall i add that to the script above. I am using a text type for the date if that is any help

Comment: `var selectedDate = new Date(selectedText+' 23:59:59');` would be my try; it's possible that I'm not thinking enough about time zones, though.